# after calling around 30 times fragmentTransaction.replace() the FragmentActivity is unexpectedly closing

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have a test app which has it's questions stored in a database. My FragmentActivity contains a fragment, which is being replaced upon new question is being selected from the AppBar. When I select a new question around 30 times the FragmentActivity unexpectedly closes and brings me on my previous Activity that was back in the stack.

On my Logcat at level Verbose I don't see anything related with my Application why it's happened.

My xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutAppbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/s202_background" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The RelativeLayout is always being replaced with a fragment upon calling fragmentTransaction.replace();
In the LinearLayout below is my AppBar which has Buttons created programatically representing each question in the database.

When a button is clicked OnClickListener is called and identifies which button is clicked and then in a new method is calling the fragmentTransaction.replace();
Here is the code for that method:

```
    private void question1() {
    testPrasanjaCursor = BazaNaPrasanja.testDatabase.query(VozackaDbContract.TABLE_NAME_TABELA_TEST, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    testPrasanjaCursor.moveToPosition(0);

    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentZnaci4);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    testPrasanjaCursor.close();
}
```

I don't know if the Sqlite database is causing it or the FragmentManager cause I don't have any information related with my Appliaction in the Verbose.

EDIT:
Logcat added, here are all the logcat since I click run on Emulator till it closes the FragmentActivity:

```
12-11 13:33:48.802 1722-1722/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
12-11 13:33:48.803 1722-1722/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86_64
12-11 13:33:48.906 1722-1722/mojavozacka.testovi_za_vozacka_dozvola W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/mojavozacka.testovi_za_vozacka_dozvola-2/lib/x86_64
12-11 13:33:48.918 1722-1722/mojavozacka.testovi_za_vozacka_dozvola I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is mojavozacka.testovi_za_vozacka_dozvola, real application class is null.
12-11 13:33:49.203 1722-1722/mojavozacka.testovi_za_vozacka_dozvola W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/mojavozacka.testovi_za_vozacka_dozvola-2/lib/x86_64
12-11 13:33:49.353 1722-1722/mojavozacka.testovi_za_vozacka_dozvola W/art: Verification of java.lang.Object mojavozacka.testovi_za_vozacka_dozvola.PocetnaActivity.access$super(mojavozacka.testovi_za_vozacka_dozvola.PocetnaActivity, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[]) took 110.107ms
12-11 13:33:49.605 1722-1729/mojavozacka.testovi_za_vozacka_dozvola W/art: Suspending all threads took: 53.041ms
12-11 13:33:49.966 1722-1752/mojavozacka.testovi_za_vozacka_dozvola D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
12-11 13:33:50.168 1722-1722/mojavozacka.testovi_za_vozacka_dozvola I/SQLiteAssetHelper: successfully opened database vozacka.db
12-11 13:33:50.170 1722-1722/mojavozacka.testovi_za_vozacka_dozvola I/SQLiteAssetHelper: successfully opened database test.db
12-11 13:33:50.177 1722-1734/mojavozacka.testovi_za_vozacka_dozvola I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 10882(1917KB) AllocSpace objects, 11(220KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 45MB/45MB, paused 4.735ms total 215.229ms
12-11 13:33:50.319 1722-1778/mojavozacka.testovi_za_vozacka_dozvola I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
12-11 13:33:50.319 1722-1778/mojavozacka.testovi_za_vozacka_dozvola D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
12-11 13:33:50.337 1722-1778/mojavozacka.testovi_za_vozacka_dozvola E/EGL_emulation: tid 1778: eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
12-11 13:33:50.337 1722-1778/mojavozacka.testovi_za_vozacka_dozvola W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7d21b2f6f780, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
12-11 13:33:50.415 1722-1734/mojavozacka.testovi_za_vozacka_dozvola I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 10885(956KB) AllocSpace objects, 6(120KB) LOS objects, 8% free, 44MB/48MB, paused 19.305ms total 217.880ms
12-11 13:33:53.844 1722-1722/mojavozacka.testovi_za_vozacka_dozvola I/SQLiteAssetHelper: successfully opened database vozacka.db
12-11 13:33:53.858 1722-1722/mojavozacka.testovi_za_vozacka_dozvola I/SQLiteAssetHelper: successfully opened database test.db
12-11 13:33:53.866 1722-1734/mojavozacka.testovi_za_vozacka_dozvola W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.410ms
12-11 13:33:53.962 1722-1778/mojavozacka.testovi_za_vozacka_dozvola E/EGL_emulation: tid 1778: eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
12-11 13:33:53.962 1722-1778/mojavozacka.testovi_za_vozacka_dozvola W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7d21b2f6f040, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
12-11 13:33:55.979 1722-1729/mojavozacka.testovi_za_vozacka_dozvola W/art: Suspending all threads took: 15.611ms
12-11 13:33:56.304 1722-1778/mojavozacka.testovi_za_vozacka_dozvola E/EGL_emulation: tid 1778: eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
12-11 13:33:56.304 1722-1778/mojavozacka.testovi_za_vozacka_dozvola W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7d21b2f6f780, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
12-11 13:33:58.573 1722-1722/mojavozacka.testovi_za_vozacka_dozvola W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
12-11 13:34:00.499 1722-1729/mojavozacka.testovi_za_vozacka_dozvola W/art: Suspending all threads took: 8.897ms
12-11 13:34:01.755 1722-1734/mojavozacka.testovi_za_vozacka_dozvola I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 5.076ms for cause Background
12-11 13:34:05.741 1722-1778/mojavozacka.testovi_za_vozacka_dozvola E/EGL_emulation: tid 1778: eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
12-11 13:34:05.741 1722-1778/mojavozacka.testovi_za_vozacka_dozvola W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7d21b2f6f040, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
12-11 13:34:08.083 1722-1722/mojavozacka.testovi_za_vozacka_dozvola W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of my answer can help you or not but you can try it, and tell me is it the same or not specialty in performance

```
yourContentView= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_main1);
yourContentView.removeAllViews();
```

Comment: you mean my main LinearLayout which has id of "layoutMain" right?

Comment: yes, the layout that you want to change its content with another question

Comment: well the layout that is chaning it's content upon a question is selected is the RelativeLayot with id "fragment_container", I am replacing it layout with another fragment when I click on a Button. I will try your answer and tell you if it works.

Comment: I've tried it and it still closes after opening 30 questions or so. Unfortunately that's not working

Comment: sorry for that, well you then posts the Logcat

Comment: I added the logcat in my question. You can check them out

Comment: I'm sorry for that but i could n't find the error, I wish I help you

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution to this. At 25 questions opened I recreate the same Activity.
It seems that the bug is related with the Activity, may be each Activity can have up to 30 Fragments replaced.